# rviz Bus error on Nvidia Jetson tx1 board

Tags: ros, rviz, jetson

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to run rviz on Nvidia Jetson Tx1 board, but the following error appears:

```
Bus error
```

Could anyone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223995/rviz-bus-error-on-nvidia-jetson-tx1-board/) by [fujisys](https://answers.ros.org/users/25110/fujisys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-01-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sally](https://answers.ros.org/users/27061/sally/) on 2016-08-29**:
Hi, have you solved this problem? Could you teach me? I meet the same problem!

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2016-10-16**:
Hi,  have you solved this problem? Could you teach me? I meet the same problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to run:
unset GTK_IM_MODULE

From the ROS Arm instruction page:
http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM

Using RVIZ
It is not recommended to run rviz on most ARM-based CPUs. They're generally too slow, and the version of OpenGL that is provided by the software (mesa) libraries it not new enough to start rviz.

'IF' you have a powerful board with a GPU and vendor-supplied OpenGL libraries, it might be possible to run rviz. The IFC6410 and the NVidia Jetson TK1 are two such boards where rviz will run, although neither is fast enough for graphics-heavy tasks such as displaying pointclouds.

Note that rviz will segfault if you have the GTK_IM_MODULE environment variable set, so it's best to unset it in your ~/.bashrc:

unset GTK_IM_MODULE

---

Originally posted by [sjobeek](https://answers.ros.org/users/25941/sjobeek/) with karma: 26 on 2016-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2016-10-16**:
Hi, i followed your advice but unsuccessed!